# Trouble connecting to json objects, setting up tick function in d3 force directed layout

Tags: json, d3.js, svg

I'm new to d3 and coding in general really. But right now I'm working on building a force directed network based on json data. What I need to do is create svg circles for the various json objects I have.

I'm trying to make 6 large circles based on each of the 6 categories I have under sector in my json file and then make small circles based on each of the objects' names (there are 47 of them in the json file). I don't know how to call them in the json array though.

Here's a sample of the json data:

```js
[
{
    "name":"Virginia Institute of Marine Science Center for Coastal Resources Management",
    "Sector":"Academia",
    "link":"http://ccrm.vims.edu/",
    "description":"Virginia Institute of Marine Science- The Center for Coastal Resources Management (CCRM) develops and supports integrated and adaptive management of coastal zone resources. To fulfill this mission, the Center undertakes research, provides advisory service, and conducts outreach education.",
    "contact":"Carl Hershner\ncarl@vims.edu\n804-684-7387",
    "reports":"TideWatch (and the Real-Time Storm Tide Observation and Forecast System) is an online, real-time water level monitoring tool developed by VIMS researchers. It provides information that can help predict the magnitude of coastal flooding in an area and allow comparison of storm tides at 9 locations within the Chesapeake Bay.\nhttp://www.vims.edu/bayinfo/tidewatch/index.php\n\nThe Recurrent Flooding Report for Tidewater and Eastern Shore localities\nhttp://www.ccrm.vims.edu/recurrent_flooding/Recurrent_Flooding_Study_web.pdf\n\nThe Comprehensive Coastal Resource Management Portal - Guidance for Tidal Shoreline Management Plans in Virginia\nhttp://www.ccrm.vims.edu/ccrmp/index.html\n\nVariety of research projects looking at ecological impacts and tools for adaptation planning\nhttp://ccrm.vims.edu/coastal_zone/climate_change/index.html\n\nDeveloping adaptation plans for localities"
  },
  {
    "name":"Virginia Tech Water Resources Center",
    "Sector":"Academia",
    "link":"http://vawatercentralnewsgrouper.wordpress.com/category/climate-change/\n\nhttp://vwrrc.vt.edu/projects.html\n\n",
    "description":"Virginia Tech hosts the Virginia Water Resources Research Center, one of 54 water resources research institutes located around the country as a result of the 1964 Federal Water Resources Research Act. The Virginia Water Resources Research Center features a stormwater best management practices website in collaboration with the Virginia Department of Environmental Quality and compiles climate-change articles and sources on a Water News blog. Virginia Tech�s Environmental and Water Resources Engineering Program has been examining impacts of sea level rise and climate change on coastal flooding and is introducing a new focus on coastal engineering.",
    "contact":"Stephen Schoenholtz\nstephen.schoenholtz@vt.edu \n540-231-0711",
    "reports":""
  },
  {
    "name":"Back Bay Restoration Foundation",
    "Sector":"Non-Governmental Organization",
    "link":"http://www.bbrf.org/",
    "description":"Back Bay Restoration Foundation (BBRF) is working on several sea level rise projects. BBRF was recently awarded a grant through the Virginia Migratory Waterfowl Stamp Grant Project to partner with U.S. Fish and Wildlife Service and Back Bay National Wildlife Refuge to restore 340 acres of high quality emergent and forested wetland habitat, as well as maintaining 260 acres of newly established submerged aquatic vegetation through refurbishment of two water control structures damaged by burrowing animals and flanking. In addition, BBRF will be funded through the Hurricane Sandy Resiliency Grant Program to partner with several organizations to restore 3783 acres forested wetlands and establish 1650 feet of living shoreline (estuarine) in the Back Bay estuary & watershed of Virginia. BBRF also hosts the Watersheds Forum each spring to provide up to date information regarding the health of Virginia Beach�s watersheds, including sea level rise.",
    "contact":"Shannon Davis\nshannon.davis@bbrf.org",
    "reports":""
  },
  {
    "name":"Chesapeake Climate Action Network",
    "Sector":"Non-Governmental Organization",
    "link":"http://chesapeakeclimate.org/",
    "description":"Chesapeake Climate Action Network has launched their Virginia Safe Coast campaign, which regards the greater Hampton Roads area as one of the country�s regions most vulnerable to sea-level rise. The campaign has demanded immediate adoption of adaptation measures to protect coastal communities and reduction of carbon emissions to slow the level of rising seas.",
    "contact":"Mike Tidwell\nmtidwell@chesapeakeclimate.org",
    "reports":""
  }
  ]
```

Also, I was having trouble with my nodes displaying earlier which was because I didn't wrap all of the code dependent on my external request within the request callback. I took care of that, but then they were all clumped in the upper left corner of my svg and I'm thinking this has something to do with the tick function? Anybody have ideas on how to fix that?

Here's the code behind the network visualization:

```js
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>  
<script type= "text/javascript">

        var w = 600,
            h = 400;
        
        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .size([w,h])
            .linkDistance([150])
            .charge([-150])
            .gravity(0.1)
//            .on("tick", tick);
 
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("height", w)
            .attr("width", h);
        
        var data; // a global

        d3.json("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1rnhq", function(error, json) {
            if (error) return console.warn(error);
            data = json;
       
        var circlesPrimary = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(data.Sector)      //Need to bind each json object to circlesSecondary by the sector. Only 1 circleSecondary for each category of sectors in the json file
            .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("r", 10)
                .call(force.drag);  
        
        var circlesSecondary = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(data.name)        //Need to bind each json object to the nodes by the name 
            .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("r", 20)
                .call(force.drag);
        
      force.on("tick", function(e) {
/*            link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                 .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                 .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                 .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
*/            
            circlesPrimary.attr("cx", function(d.Sector) { return d.x; })
                          .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
          
            circlesSecondary.attr("cx", function(d.name) { return d.x; })
                            .attr("cy", function(d.name) { return d.y; });
     
        force.start();
        
        });
```

Comment: The Json you have pasted above is different from what you want..it does not have category nor can i see any 47 object names. Could you please rephrase this question with what you want and what you have achieved. In total the problem spec is not clear for any one to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your code. Hope this helps.
For different size of the circle, you don't need to have separate circle variable created, just change the radius with types.

```
var w = 600,
    h = 400;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
       .attr("height", w)
       .attr("width", h);

    var data; // a global

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .size([w,h])
        .linkDistance([150])
        .charge([-150])
        .gravity(0.1)
        .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .style("border", "1px solid black")
    .attr("height", h);

var circles = svg.selectAll(".node");

   d3.json("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1rnhq", function(error, json) {
        if (error) return console.warn(error);
        data = json;
        console.log(data);

        force.nodes(data)
          .start();

// Update nodes.
  circles = circles.data(data);

  circles.exit().remove();


  var nodeEnter = circles.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .style("fill", "#3182bd")
      .call(force.drag);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
            .attr("r",  function(d) { return d.sector == "Academia" ? 20 :10 });

    });

function tick() {
  circles.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks so much! I have nodes for each of my 47 json objects. What I need to do though is create 6 more nodes for each of the different types of sector: Academia, Commonwealth, NGO, Federal, Military, and State Legislature.

Here is the json data: https://api.myjson.com/bins/1rnhq

Do you know how I can get that done?

Comment: function(d) { return d.sector == "Academia" ? 20 :10 }.. you need to define all the types here with different radius. With my experience with D3, i have done it this way

Comment: what would the syntax look like to do that?

Comment: same as i have added in the previous comment it goes like this... 
.attr("r", function(d) { return d.sector == "Academia" ? 20 : "Commonwealth" ? 10 : 5;)